# Devise gem: what's the difference between config.remember_for and config.timeout_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Ideally, I would like to automatically remember my users once they login, and keep them logged in for a few weeks until asking for credentials again. Shall I then set `config.remember_for = 3.weeks` or `config.timeout_in = 3.weeks` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are two separate entities (even two separate modules in `Devise`).

First (`remember_for`), is to remember user for a specified amount of time (usually days or months), so that he can get into the app without going though the login procedure every time.

Second (`timeout_in`), is to logout user after he is idle for some time. This is the same as when you logged in to your bank account, and it would log you out after ten or twenty minutes of inactivity to protect your confidential information.

So, `remember_for` is the one you should choose.

Comment: Link to documentation might be nice.

Comment: Also what would happen if `remember_for` is set to 1 week and `timeout_in` is set for 1 day. Wouldn't this set up a contradictory setting?